# How to make CSS Grid last row to take up remaining space

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid with variable number of rows and I want the last one to be 1fr height.

Something like this:

[image]

Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use flex for this.

The parent container should have `display: flex;`. We want to use it vertically, so we will change the flex direction like this `flex-direction: column;`.

After this, we will use the property `flex-shrink: 1;` for every child. This way, it will take only the space needed/specified. The tricks for the last child is to use the property `flex-grow: 1;` so it will take the available space.

See the snippet below:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.fill-height {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fill-height > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height:2em;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.fill-height > div:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="fill-height">
  <div>
    row 1 (shrink)
  </div>
  <div>
    row 2 (shrink)
  </div>
  <div>
    row 3 (grow)
  </div>
</section>
```

Link to [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bmwcu9x/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I was hoping to be able to use grid, but I really think that's not possible.