# CSS: Having a grid item to span over all the remaining columns in the row

Tags: css

Here is a small code I've done

https://codepen.io/Scipionh/pen/yLabxWx

My requirements are the followings:

- each item has to have the same width (apart from the other block)
- the width of the container is defined and I need to have items touching its border
- I have an unknown number of items (here 8 before the other block but it may be more or less)
- the Other block should span over all the remaining columns in the row it is in

In my example, I would like to have the Other block fitting in the second row.

Basically the culprit here is

```
grid-column: 2/-1;
```

as 2 is an hardcoded value.

I **KNOW** this is a flexbox job as we want to consume the remaining space (and have already done it with it) !

But any idea how to fix my grid solution?

Cheers

Comment: as I commented in your previous deleted question, this is a flexbox job, there is nothing in CSS grid *fill remaining columns* Unless you write a ton of media query to cover each case individually

Comment: read the point (6) in the accepted answer of the duplicate

Comment: @TemaniAfif If you read what I wrote, you could clearly see that I have done it correctly with flex. So I am aware "this is a flexbox job". The question was more about, how to do it with grid and I was aware there was no "native property" to do it. So the question was more about how to tweak my html/css to achieve it. So not really a duplicate mate. You mentioned it could be done with "tons of media query", you may propose a solution ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56339098/8620333

Comment: Thanks this was the expected answer.