# Grid items grow when alone in row

Tags: css, grid

Is there a way to have a grid item that is alone in a row take up the rest of the space, if you have more than one column. Something like flex-grow.

Example

```
<div class="controller">
    <div class="item">hello</div>
    <div class="item">hello</div>
    <div class="item">hello</div>
    <div class="item">hello</div>
    <div class="item">bye</div>
</div>
<style>
    .controller {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        gap: .75rem .75rem;
    }
    .item {
        background-color: aquamarine;
    }
</style>
```

I want the bye block to take up the rest of the space automatically, but it does this:
[image]

I want it to do this automatically if its alone in a row.
[image]

EDIT:
This comment doesn't answer the question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75067528/8620333
a) its not automatic
b) if you use the order property it will mess around with :child selector.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75067528/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif its not automatic. Also as soon as you start playing around with the order css property it breaks everything.

Comment: not sure what are you talking about ... there is no order property in the link I shared

Comment: yes, thats because the person who commented didn't consider the scenario. The commenter suggested targeting a specific item using the :nth-child selector, and if you use the order property (which the commenter doesn't), then the order of the children changes.